# TypeError: No matching declaration found after variable lookup balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply_

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

So I am using a combination of Openzepplin solidity contracts to create a burnable token with a supply cap of 3million.
I keep getting the above error on the last contract and I have no idea why. I have tried replacing balanceOf[msg.sender] with balances[msg.sender], totalSupply_ with totalSupply, and re-declaring the existence of a public uint256 in the local contract (despite the fact that it should be inherited.

The following is my flattened contract with all dependencies (thanks for your help!):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

// File: contracts\token\ERC20\ERC20.sol

/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 {
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);

  function balanceOf(address _who) public view returns (uint256);

  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender)
    public view returns (uint256);

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool);

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
    public returns (bool);

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)
    public returns (bool);

  event Transfer(
    address indexed from,
    address indexed to,
    uint256 value
  );

  event Approval(
    address indexed owner,
    address indexed spender,
    uint256 value
  );
}

// File: contracts\math\SafeMath.sol

/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that revert on error
 */
library SafeMath {

  /**
  * @dev Multiplies two numbers, reverts on overflow.
  */
  function mul(uint256 _a, uint256 _b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
    // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
    // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/pull/522
    if (_a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    uint256 c = _a * _b;
    require(c / _a == _b);

    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Integer division of two numbers truncating the quotient, reverts on division by zero.
  */
  function div(uint256 _a, uint256 _b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(_b > 0); // Solidity only automatically asserts when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = _a / _b;
    // assert(_a == _b * c + _a % _b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold

    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Subtracts two numbers, reverts on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).
  */
  function sub(uint256 _a, uint256 _b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(_b <= _a);
    uint256 c = _a - _b;

    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Adds two numbers, reverts on overflow.
  */
  function add(uint256 _a, uint256 _b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = _a + _b;
    require(c >= _a);

    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Divides two numbers and returns the remainder (unsigned integer modulo),
  * reverts when dividing by zero.
  */
  function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    require(b != 0);
    return a % b;
  }
}

// File: contracts\token\ERC20\StandardToken.sol

/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
 * Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20 {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping (address => uint256) private balances;

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private allowed;

  uint256 public totalSupply_;

  /**
  * @dev Total number of tokens in existence
  */
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(
    address _owner,
    address _spender
   )
    public
    view
    returns (uint256)
  {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
  * @dev Transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
    require(_to != address(0));

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);
    require(_to != address(0));

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Increase the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _addedValue The amount of tokens to increase the allowance by.
   */
  function increaseApproval(
    address _spender,
    uint256 _addedValue
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = (
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue));
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Decrease the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To decrement
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _subtractedValue The amount of tokens to decrease the allowance by.
   */
  function decreaseApproval(
    address _spender,
    uint256 _subtractedValue
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    uint256 oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue >= oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Internal function that mints an amount of the token and assigns it to
   * an account. This encapsulates the modification of balances such that the
   * proper events are emitted.
   * @param _account The account that will receive the created tokens.
   * @param _amount The amount that will be created.
   */
  function _mint(address _account, uint256 _amount) internal {
    require(_account != 0);
    totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.add(_amount);
    balances[_account] = balances[_account].add(_amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), _account, _amount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Internal function that burns an amount of the token of a given
   * account.
   * @param _account The account whose tokens will be burnt.
   * @param _amount The amount that will be burnt.
   */
  function _burn(address _account, uint256 _amount) internal {
    require(_account != 0);
    require(balances[_account] > _amount);

    totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.sub(_amount);
    balances[_account] = balances[_account].sub(_amount);
    emit Transfer(_account, address(0), _amount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Internal function that burns an amount of the token of a given
   * account, deducting from the sender's allowance for said account. Uses the
   * internal _burn function.
   * @param _account The account whose tokens will be burnt.
   * @param _amount The amount that will be burnt.
   */
  function _burnFrom(address _account, uint256 _amount) internal {
    require(allowed[_account][msg.sender] > _amount);

    // Should https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/707 be accepted,
    // this function needs to emit an event with the updated approval.
    allowed[_account][msg.sender] = allowed[_account][msg.sender].sub(_amount);
    _burn(_account, _amount);
  }
}

// File: contracts\token\ERC20\BurnableToken.sol

/**
 * @title Burnable Token
 * @dev Token that can be irreversibly burned (destroyed).
 */
contract BurnableToken is StandardToken {

  event Burn(address indexed burner, uint256 value);

  /**
   * @dev Burns a specific amount of tokens.
   * @param _value The amount of token to be burned.
   */
  function burn(uint256 _value) public {
    _burn(msg.sender, _value);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Burns a specific amount of tokens from the target address and decrements allowance
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _value uint256 The amount of token to be burned
   */
  function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public {
    _burnFrom(_from, _value);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Overrides StandardToken._burn in order for burn and burnFrom to emit
   * an additional Burn event.
   */
  function _burn(address _who, uint256 _value) internal {
    super._burn(_who, _value);
    emit Burn(_who, _value);
  }
}
/**
 * @title KWATT_Token Token
 * @dev Token that can be irreversibly burned (destroyed).
 */
contract KWATT_Token is BurnableToken {
    string public name = "Token";
    string public symbol = "TKN";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 300000000;
constructor() public {
  totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `balances` instead of `balanceOf`, but you'll first need to switch that variable's visibility to `internal` instead of `private`.